# Find all lines containing string - summarize and count them

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have a lot of files in several subfolders that include a string `type="abc_` - I'm not too sure how many variants of `abc_` there is - so I want to know how many occurrences of the unknown `type="abc_` are in within my files.

I'd hope to get something that is like line containing

```
"type="abc_0815 found 50 times
"type="abc_0816 found 32 times
...

and so on.
```

If I do like that:

```
grep -rni 'type="abc_' * | wc
```

I already know its 14905 occurrences with `type="abc_`.

Can somebody help me on that?

Comment: True that - sorry. I have a lot of files cotainting that string. Those files a located in a lot of subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `find` to get a file listing passes it to `cat` and parses the output with `awk`:

```
find . -type f |
xargs -I xx cat "xx" | awk '/type="abc_/{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/type="abc_/){ d[$i]++ } } } 
  END{ for(i in d){ print i"\tfound",d[i],"times." } }'

type="abc_4  found 1 times.
type="abc_3  found 2 times.
type="abc_6  found 1 times.
type="abc_2  found 2 times.
type="abc_10 found 3 times.
type="abc_5  found 1 times.
```

It uses find instead of a simple `cat *` to be more flexible what to search for.

`xargs .. cat | ..` can be shortened with `find . -type f -exec cat {} + | awk ..`

Comment: Thanks Sir! This exactly does the trick! <3 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

just add `-c` flag to have grep count it for you.

In case there is too many 0 results, filter out with awk

```
  grep -rnic 'type="abc_' * | awk -F: '$NF>0'
```

Comment: Thats cool - it shows me how many findings there were in those files. Is it possible to get also the exact finding? like found 'type="abc_0815" 2 times and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Try similar this:

```bsh
grep -rni 'type="abc_' * |sed -n "s/.*\(abc_[0-9]*\).*/\1/p"|uniq -c| sed  "s/\(.*\)\(abc.*\)/\2 found \1 times/"
```